# Is the usage of "mitigation" restricted to (human) actors?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions

In the context of positive and negative feedbacks in the earth system and climate change:
I feel that *mitigation* is something that has to be actively done by someone, but since I am neither a linguist nor a native speaker, I can't properly argue for or against it.

Is the usage of "mitigation" restricted to (human) actors? Or can mitigation be a passive effect of natural processes?

Answer (score 6):

Mitigation does not need a human actor. Consider the following sentence.

> The unseasonal rains mitigated the problem of wildfires.

Comment: I found another: "Beavers can help mitigate the effects of climate change"

Comment: It is a good example sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Example sentences in respected online dictionaries contain few if any examples of a *force / natural cause* rather than an *agent* (with volition) as the actor, in sentences containing the related verb. In fact, most example sentences contain a covert agent:

> - *drainage schemes have helped to mitigate this problem* [[Oxford Dictionaries ... via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mitigate+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=wE1JY9OnI5ST8gKX5oT4DA&ved=0ahUKEwjTh5-11N_6AhWUiVwKHRczAc8Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=mitigate+meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCwgAEIAEELEDEIMBMgcIABCABBADMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BQgAEJECOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6CAguEIAEELEDOgQIABBDOgcILhDUAhBDOggIABCABBCxAzoICC4Q)]

..............

> - *Only international co-operation can mitigate environmental damage.* [[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mitigate)]

However, sentences with a non-volitional actor (not even in the bakground)  are not uncommon; here is an example from an article in [The National Library of Medicine by Toll-Riera, Olombrada, Castro-Giner and Wagner](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35857489/):

> - *It involved genomic changes that occurred in a highly parallel fashion and mitigated the effects of protein misfolding.*

And another example from [Pruffle.mit.ed](http://pruffle.mit.edu/3.00/Lecture_02_web/node24.html):

> - *Le Chatelier's principle says that a system will respond to mitigate the effect of an implied stimulus*.

The use of the noun *mitigation* mirrors that of the verb.